# Change createClass to Component

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React so sorry for the really basic question. I have searched on Google and tried other StackOverflow posts but nothing worked. I am trying to create a form with validation and I found this example:

```
import t from 'tcomb-form'

const FormSchema = t.struct({
  name: t.String,         // a required string
  age: t.maybe(t.Number), // an optional number
  rememberMe: t.Boolean   // a boolean
})

    const App = React.createClass({

      onSubmit(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault()
        const value = this.refs.form.getValue()
        if (value) {
          console.log(value)
        }
      },

      render() {
        return (
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <t.form.Form ref="form" type={FormSchema} />
            <div className="form-group">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        )
      }

    })
```

However I want to convert it to a normal way with:

```
export class GiveFeedback extends Component {...}
```

Here is my attempt:

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import t from 'tcomb-form'

```
export class GiveFeedback extends Component {

  const FormSchema = t.struct({
  name: t.String,         // a required string
  age: t.maybe(t.Number), // an optional number
  rememberMe: t.Boolean   // a boolean
})

  onSubmit(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault()
    const value = this.refs.form.getValue()
    if (value) {
      console.log(value)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <t.form.Form ref="form" type={FormSchema} />
        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    )
  }

}

export default GiveFeedback
```

However, when I run the code I get this error:

> Unexpected token (7:10)
>
> 5 | export class GiveFeedback extends Component {
>     6 | 
>    7 |     const FormSchema = t.struct({
>      |           ^
>   8 |   name: t.String,         // a required string
>   9 |   age: t.maybe(t.Number), // an optional number
>   10 |   rememberMe: t.Boolean   // a boolean

I was hoping someone could help.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

everything is okay you just place const in class so its not valid

remove your code and place out of class

```
 const FormSchema = t.struct({
  name: t.String,         // a required string
  age: t.maybe(t.Number), // an optional number
  rememberMe: t.Boolean   // a boolean
})

export class GiveFeedback extends Component {
......
}
```

or you can place const in render() function too

info: any custom method that defines in react component will require reference of `this`  without this you cant use setState and other class methods

there are many way to bind this to method

1.

```
export class GiveFeedback extends Component {
  constructor(){
   super();
   this.yourMethod = this.yourMethod.bind(this);
 }
 yourMethod(){
 //now you get this.state and any other object of class
 }
}
```

2.

```
export class GiveFeedback extends Component {
  constructor(){
   super();
 }

  yourMethod(){
    //now you get this.state and any other object of class
  }

  render(){
    //bind runtime 
    return(<Text onPress={this.yourMethod.bind(this)}>click</Text>)
   }
}
```

3.

```
export class GiveFeedback extends Component {
  constructor(){
   super();
 }

  yourMethod = ()=>{ 
     // this style is es6 so no need to bind and scope remain same 
    //now you get this.state and any other object of class
  }
}
```

Comment: I put the const outside the class and when the form is generated and once i enter some data into the fields and click submit i get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'refs' of undefined` for the line `const value = this.refs.form.getValue()` I also put the `const` inside the render and same error

Comment: you forgot to bind submit method  use this 

onSubmit = (evt) => {...}

Comment: or this.onSubmit.bind(this);

Comment: Ive seen this kind of syntax before. where do I write this `this.onSubmit.bind(this);` also what does it mean to bind something?

Comment: Sweet, that seemed to work thank you! as a side question and i dont expect you to answer this if you dont want to because its not part of the original question but the `console.log()` produces null. any reason why this is? I copy and pasted the example

Comment: try to log this.ref and see what you are getting

Comment: Cant seem to find anything useful :(, would you be able to run the code and see why I dont get anything back?

Comment: I have one last question. how do I add a return statement inside a const? i am trying to make custom validation messages I tried this https://pastebin.com/s4RKrb1k but it doesnt like `return n >= 18);`

Answer (score 0):

You are duplicating the `export` keyword:

```
export class GiveFeedback extends Component {
// ...
export default GiveFeedback
```

According to ES6 `export` documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) you could use any of these two options:

```
export default class GiveFeedback extends Component {
// or
class GiveFeedback extends Component {
  // ... your class definition here
}
export default GiveFeedback
```

I'd recommend you the second option, since it's easy to add some decorator later (like redux):

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(GiveFeedback);
```

**Plus**

Take a look at [redux-form](https://redux-form.com) to implement forms with validations. I use it and it's very useful and acceptably documented.

Good luck!